# Error when compiling a 'minted' listings inside a 'memoir' subfloat

Tags: errors, subfloats, minted

I'm trying to compile the following minimal example:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

% Enable subfloats within figures
\newsubfloat{figure}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\subbottom{%
\begin{minted}{c}
test;
\end{minted}
}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

but I get an error:

```
! Argument of \FV@BeginScanning has an extra }.
<inserted text> 
                \par 
l.13 \end{minted}}
```

I've tried replacing the `minted` environment with a `inputminted` which reads the code from a file, but to no avail.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `minted` environment can't work in the argument to another command, because the produced file which is input (and removed) uses the `Verbatim` environment.

A solution is to save the `minted` environment in a box and then use it:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

% Enable subfloats within figures
\newsubfloat{figure}
\newsavebox{\mintedbox}

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{lrbox}{\mintedbox}
\begin{minipage}{\textwidth} % add here for the width
\begin{minted}{c}
test;
\end{minted}
\end{minipage}
\end{lrbox}
\subbottom{\usebox{\mintedbox}}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

A fancier solution is to do that without having to remember doing it, by defining a suitable environment. The width reserved for the listing is a mandatory argument, while the first and second optional arguments have the same meaning as for the `\subbottom` command.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{xparse}
% Enable subfloats within figures
\newsubfloat{figure}
\newsavebox{\mintedbox}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{mintedsubbottom}{oom}
 {\begin{lrbox}{\mintedbox}\begin{minipage}{#3}}
 {\end{minipage}\end{lrbox}%
  \IfNoValueTF{#1}
    {\subbottom{\usebox{\mintedbox}}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
       {\subbottom[#1]{\usebox{\mintedbox}}}
       {\subbottom[#1][#2]{\usebox{\mintedbox}}}%
    }%
 }

\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
\begin{mintedsubbottom}[Caption]{\textwidth}
\begin{minted}{c}
test;
\end{minted}
\end{mintedsubbottom}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```