# minted package call from function

Tags: minted

My aim is to call source(highlighted by minted package) in one of the input.tex file instead of master tex. 
This one does not work :

```
\documentclass{uoyths}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\input{chap0.tex}   %Content
     \begin{mainMatterEnv}          \CallMintedCodeFromAnotherFile{} 
        \end{mainMatterEnv}
\end{document}
```

in chap0.tex file :

```
\def\CallMintedCodeFromAnotherFile
{
\begin{minted}{c}
int main()
{
    printf("hello, world");
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}
}
```

This one does work in the same file and same pc, any idea ?

```
\documentclass{uoyths}
\usepackage{minted}
\begin{document}
\input{chap0.tex}   %Content
     \begin{mainMatterEnv}
\begin{minted}{c}
int main()
{
    printf("hello, world");
    return 0;
}
\end{minted}        
        \end{mainMatterEnv}
\end{document}
```

Error message is : 
[image]

I found the solution and post it to my blog as well.
http://www.ozturkibrahim.com/highlighting-source-code-for-latex/
The solution is :
I have put the piece of code to  hello.cpp instead of directly inside \def and then I read it from this source file inside \def. It works perfectly:

```
\def\CallMintedCodeFromAnotherFile
{
\inputminted{c++}{hello.cpp}
}
```

Comment: Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: Can you provide a MWE? The packages you load, the order in which you include other files etc might be relevant to the question...

Comment: I have put all of them by editing the original questions.

Comment: Pardon me, but the `uoyths` class is not really widespread? In your MWE there is also a `\input` command to be commented out. How about trying the `listings` package if you want to provide programing source with `LaTeX'?

Comment: There is no relation with uoyths because I have tried it \documentclass{article} without uoyths and the def with minted piece still doesnt work. Why should i remove \input ? \def\CallMintedCodeFromAnotherFile is already inside the input.

Comment: @io517: Trying the MWE you provided, one has to comment the `\input` statement again, since there is no `chap0.tex`, if one does not copy and paste it also from your post. But I agree with you -- it does not work with `article` or `scrbook` either.

Comment: You can't use verbatim content, like `minted` environments, inside commands; instead, you will probably need to save in a box.  See [this](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/102416/error-when-compiling-a-minted-listings-inside-a-memoir-subfloat/102439#102439).